# Reorder a pandas dataframe by second column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to reorder a pandas dataframe with the second column:

```
  colors        numbers
0    red      '1 - 49 ch'
1  white    '10 - 490 ch'
3   blue  '100 - 4900 ch'
4   green  '2 - 3000 ch'
5   blue  '10 - 4900 ch'
6   blue  '1 - 49 ch'
```

This columns contains string that I need to split and order by the first element to have this result:

```
  colors        numbers
0    red      '1 - 49 ch'
1   blue  '1 - 49 ch'
2   green  '2 - 3000 ch'
3  white    '10 - 490 ch'
4   blue  '10 - 4900 ch'
5   blue  '100 - 4900 ch'
```

How can I looping thru the second column to get the result I need?

```
for i in df['numbers']:
    print(i.split(" - ")[0])
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

We can try extracting the numbers, and sort on them:

```
(df.join(df.numbers.str.extract('(\d+) - (\d+)').astype(int))
   .sort_values([0,1], kind='mergesort')
   .drop([0,1], axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
  colors          numbers
0    red      '1 - 49 ch'
6   blue      '1 - 49 ch'
4  green    '2 - 3000 ch'
1  white    '10 - 490 ch'
5   blue   '10 - 4900 ch'
3   blue  '100 - 4900 ch'
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `index_natsorted` from `natsort`

```
from natsort import index_natsorted
df=df.iloc[index_natsorted(df.numbers)]
```

Comment: dont forget to add pip install natsort as its not part of standard lib i believe :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use split you can add a new row with :

```
 df['numbers2']=df.numbers.str.split('-').str[0].astype('int')
```

and then apply sort_values on this new column